# How to ensure Wallpaper overlay is on the same page as Figure

Tags: floats, wallpaper

I have a full-page figure which I want to be shown over a full-page image.

My problem is that the overlay image appears on a different page to the figure.

I am using `wallpaper` package to produce the overlay. However, I'm happy to switch to any other solution which will allow me to overlay image over the whole page (no margins).

Is there a reliable way to have them on the same page?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{img/overlay}

\begin{figure}
  \LARGE\lipsum[4-5]
  \caption{Lipsum}
  \label{fig:hello}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tikz` as usual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\myback}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (current page.north west)
        {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \myback{example-image-a}
  \LARGE\lipsum[4-5]
  \caption{Lipsum}
  \label{fig:hello}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-15]

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Harish, it worked very well but I now realise I need the background which anchors at the north-west of the *figure* not the *page*. Is there a simple fix for that, e.g. changing `(current page.north west)` to something else?

Comment: @roldugin You can load \usetikzlibrary{calc}` and use `at ($(current page.north west) + (x cm,y cm)$)`. Change `x` and `y` as you want.